# Kuberenetes deployed application can not execute swagger API

Tags: kubernetes, swagger, swagger-ui

I have deployed application on Kubernetes and the application has one post Rest api and that has Swagger API.

I have added network policy for the application to access it from out side. I could able to access the application and open swagger UI. But while executing the API I am getting error "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource". Looking at the few threads on Google it seems issue is with CORS. Has anybody encountered such issue and fixed it?

When I run the application on local everything worked fine and only on Kubernetes I am getting this error.

Comment: What's the error message on the Console tab of the browser developer tools?

Comment: In FireFox webdeveloper console I could see "Blocked Loading mixed active content <URL_NAME>.  Type Error "Network error when attempting to fetch resource"

Comment: Please describe in more details your environment, and if possible post the yaml files from your resources. Are you using ingress to reach the application? In nginx-ingress you need to enable CORS to make it work. See [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors)